# Avoid mousemove on absolutely positioned children elements

Tags: javascript, css, dom, mousemove

I am trying to understand **mousemove** Event on absolute elements.

I made a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/saikiranmarripati/pen/pqBGrw) to demonstrate what i wanted.

I need mousemove to be captured on **#main** element, But not on any of its children that are positioned absolutely.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="main">
  <div class="btn">Click Me</div>
</div>
<div id="output">

</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#main').on('mousemove',function( e ) {
  var msg = "mouse move ";
  msg += e.pageX + ", " + e.pageY;
  $( "#output" ).html(msg);
});

});
```

Comment: You mean they should like block the event from bubbling onto the parent?

Answer (score 1):

Simply check who's the target in your event handler, and if it is one of those you want to block the event, return early.

In current configuration, it is the same as checking if the target is indeed `#main`, a.k.a [jQuery's $event.currentTarget](https://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/).

```js
$('#main').on('mousemove', function(e) {
  // here we only want the events of #main
  // so any other target is irrelevant
  if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) return;
  var msg = "mouse move ";
  msg += e.pageX + ", " + e.pageY;
  $("#output").html(msg);
});
$('#main').on('mouseout', function() {
  $("#output").html('');
});
$('#main>.btn').on('click', e=> $("#output").html('can still click'));
```

```css
#main {
  float: left;
  background: yellow;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
}

#main .btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  z-index: 2;
  border: 0;
  background: blue;
  color: #FFF;
}

#main .btn .innerbtn {
  padding: 10px;
}

#output {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #efefef;
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <div class="btn">
    <div class="innerbtn">Click Me</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="output">

</div>
```